# Maven local repository

Tags: maven

I want Maven to work offline. I downloaded all artifacts like spring and hibernate onto my computer. Then I tried to set up Maven to use local repository only. I followed instructions to point Maven to local repository. However every time I tried to load spring mvc project, I got the errors like this:

Offline / Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile
Offline / Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile

I checked the local repository. The jar and pom files are there. I can't figure out what is wrong with my configuration. Can someone help me out here?

Thanks.

Jerry

Answer (score 5):

You probably messed up your settings.xml.

Correct way to prepare for offline is this:

```
mvn install dependency:go-offline
```

The answer bilash.saha gave will not work for multi module projects.

After first command finished, you may test that everything is ok by running

```
mvn -o package
```

To save you a from typing "-o" every time use this settings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <settings>
  <offline>true</offline>
 </settings>
```

Comment: Doesn't work after some runs of your command. `Non-resolvable import POM: Cannot access <myid> (<myserver>) in offline mode and the artifact org.jboss.bom.eap:jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools:pom:6.2.0.GA has not been downloaded from it before.`

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
mvn dependency:go-offline
```

then build your project offline using the '-o' flag:

```
mvn install -o
```