# Maven distinct dependencies?

Tags: maven, dependencies, repository, maven-plugin, maven-3

**I wonder if it is possible, to stop Maven 3.0 downloading old libraries and use only distinct versions.** 
(prefering the local repo and the versions where i downloaded Javadoc and sources manually)

For example using JUnit 3.8.2, 4.8.1 and the newest 4.x, but never <3.8.1, 4.5, 4.6-Snapshot etc.

Background: I have my actual projects and local repo on first drive (SSD) with limited space. 
If i try an maven archetype to start a new project (often for learning a new theme), maven like downloading i.e. junit 4.5
but i don't like to edit the pom manually looking over my local versions, thinking about compatibilties
and i don't like to purge and download the prefered dependencies again and again.

**Are there any tools, plugins, settings or best practices to get this going ?**

What i tried so far...

- [going Offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932109/maven-local-repository) doesn't help cause my preferred IDE offer download manually only for doc+src
      => "Could not resolve dependencies... The repository system is offline but the artifact ... is not available in the local repository."
- best practice for now is (netbeans) <s>in context menu "Remove
  dependecy" on project and</s>  
  "Add as Dependecy.." from local repository
  tree. (like [screenshots](http://scalapractice.blogspot.com/2012/01/maven-distinct-dependencies.html) ?)

Comment: Which version of Maven are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specify the versions in your pom.xml (as a dependency, or excluding an older version from a dependency), it shouldn't download any other jars than those specified (or excluded).

Comment: When i start with using a (for me new) archtype it mostly generates a pom with any versions that where actual when the archetype was created. I can edit the generated pom and specify the versions, i knew. 

Your answer will be helpful, if there is a chance to generally exclude older versions. Thanks.

Comment: If you're using archetypes, there's not much you can do, since the point of the archetype is to use the defaults it provides. The easiest thing (if not purely brute-force) is to run the archetype, edit the pom, delete your local repo entirely, and resync. The IDE plugin should handle the resync on the next build anyway.

Comment: You should also edit the question, retag or comment on the question itself, adding the version of Maven you're using. There are features that are different across 2.0.x, 2.1.x, 2.2.x and 3.x in how versioning is handled. Someone else may have a better answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

After reading much new stuff i finally agree to [Spencer Kormos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8528/spencer-kormos):

> If you're using archetypes, there's not much you can do...

**Best practice for me is now this:**

**Small solution**

 - create the pom using an archetype 
 - add `<dependencyManagement../>` decribing the prefered dependency in the top of the pom 
 - add `<scope>provided</scope>`  
 - optionaly you can add the `<exclusions.. />`
 - remove the conflicting `<version../>` tags in the generated pom 
 - the `<dependencyManagement../>` section i will use for copy/paste in other projects

**Greater solution (hopefully) ?** 

 - create a parent/master pom with `<dependencyManagement../>` of prefered artifacts 
 - use the from archetype generated pom as module or child-project
 - use the master pom for grouping dependencies with `<packaging>pom</packaging>`

**Some of the stuff i read the last day** only two links allowed :-( 
Maven-Model (look for dependencyManagement under [project](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.3/maven-model/maven.html#class_project))
[Maven: The Complete Reference, Chapter 3.6.1. Grouping Dependencies](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html)

Comment: +1 for the parent pom to include the dependencyManagement tag. If you follow Sonotype's best practices, this is where you're supposed to manage exclusions anyway, and you can deploy a full parent project, specifying your versions for those jars that you want to use.